# Python Using For Loop: Is it possible to reuse the prior number to multiply it again inside the list?

Tags: python

I don't know if im making any sense, please pardon the way my english is constructed but i have this code.

```
initial_int = float(input("Enter your initial investment: "))
interest_rate = [0.02, 0.03, 0.015, 0.06]

for a in interest_rate:
    #formula
    print( a * initial_int + initial_int)
```

My goal is to input a number and then I will try to multiply it inside each elements of the list, then i want to reuse the prior number to multiply it again to the next number inside the list. Here's my expected output.

Input number:
1000

```
#and then i want the 1000 to be multiply by each element inside the list interest_rate = [0.02, 0.03, 0.015, 0.06]
```

Output:

1020

1050

1065

1125

Answer (score 0):

You just need to multiply the current amount by `a`, and add it to the current amount itself. Easiest way to do that is:

```
for a in interest_rate:
    initial_int += a*initial_int
    print(initial_int)
```

Answer (score 0):

A single `for` loop is sufficient, yet you can also use the `accumulate` function from `itertools` module, since from python v3.8 accumulate support `inital` as an optional argument.

```py
import itertools

initial_int = float(input("Enter your initial investment: "))
interest_rate = [0.02, 0.03, 0.015, 0.06]

print(list(itertools.accumulate(interest_rate, lambda ini, x: ini+ x*ini, initial = initial_int)))
```

> output: [1000, 1020.0, 1050.6, 1066.359, 1130.34054]

for more details check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).